# How to send a unique id to the next page while navigating using Link in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router, next-link

I am trying to send an `id` to the next page when the user navigates.

I have a homepage where I am fetching an Array of data and using `.map` to display it in a kind of card-based UI.

Now, when the user clicks the card, they will be navigated to the next page display details about that card.

Suppose the home page is here - `localhost:3000`

And user clicks the card with an id of `234`

They will be navigated to the next page as :

The next page is as - `localhost:3000/user/234`

Now here I want to display information about that card with an id of 234. FOr that I do need to make a fetch request as such fetch(`https://userdatabase/234`)

The above `234` is a dynamic id for sure, How can I let this `fetch` request know to change this id every time a new card has been clicked? Or in other words, How this page "knows" the id of the card ?

Right now, I', using a workaround as :

1. When the user is at the second page, the URL will be like this `localhost:3000/user/386`
2. Get this id in NextJS using `useRouter` as :

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
`const router = useRouter()`



fetch(`localhost:3000/user/${router?.query?.user})
```

I understand taking id from URL and making a fresh quest is not ideal at all and this is causing stale caching issue on the second page.

How do I resolve this in a better way?

Thanks so much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a dynamic route : [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

for your case make a file `pages/user/[id].js`

**1. Client side**

access id with this snippet :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  return <p>{id}</p>
}

export default Component
```

**2. Server side**

you can use it any of the [data fetching functions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview)

Snippet for SSR :

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {

  const { id } = params
  // fetch data from database with id

  return {
    props: {},  // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

More on what gets passed to data fetching functions as Context : [Context Parameter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing exactly. `fetch(`localhost:3000/user/${router?.query?.user})` -> here I'm getting the id with the help of router as well. Is there a better way?

Comment: did you make [id].js file? note the name, it is important

Comment: do you want server side rendering for the id page?

Comment: Yes SSR for id page

Comment: Also I did make the [id].js page. In my case it is [userid] hence  const { userid } = router.query

Comment: i have updated the answer for server side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be ideal if we are dealing with only SSR. I have a NextJS + react-query based setup. Please check my file here -> https://gist.github.com/abhinav-anshul/050aa857351f3fb5c81dc57c0a027eea

Comment: Also this is how we setup NextJS + react-query -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixZRNz76W90

Comment: React Query is client side, you cant do SSR with it.

Comment: React Query handles state at Server Side, then fetches it to client

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to the dependencies array of `useEffect()`.
Something along these lines:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [page, changePage] = useState();
  // `query` can only be fully parsed client-side
  // so `isReady` flag is needed 
  const { query, isReady } = router;
  const { id } = query;
  // also need to parse the query value to undefined or string
  const parsedID = id === undefined
    ? undefined
    : Array.isArray(id)
    ? id[0]
    : id;

  useEffect(() => {
    // refuse to run the effect if query is not ready
    // or ID is undefined
    if (!isReady || !parsedID ) {
      return;
    }

    // this looks ugly
    // but pure promise syntax is even uglier
    // and `useEffect()` doesn't accept async functions
    (async () => {
      // errors are assumed to be handled in the `_app` component
      // so no error-handling logic here
      const response = await fetch(`localhost:3000/user/${parsedID}`);
      const newPage = await response.json();
      changePage(newPage);
    })()

  }, [isReady, parsedID]);
  
  return (
    <>
      {!page
        // show loading placeholder until the page is fetched
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        // pass the `page` value to whatever component you need
        : ...
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using SSR only fetching. `useEffect` wont be ideal for me

Comment: You still have to validate the query value and even refuse to fetch depending on its result, because the call like `fetch(`localhost:3000/user/${router?.query?.user})` will end up as `fetch(`localhost:3000/user/undefined)` if not all conditions are met.